# Declaring Dynamic 2D Vector in class

Tags: c++, stl, vector

We're trying to use a 2D vector because we want a 2D array that will grow dynamically.

We tried this:
In the class declaration:

```
    vector<vector<double> > table;
```

But then table doesn't seem to be allocated. We get a segfault when we try to access members.

So then we tried this:

Class Declaration:

```
    vector<vector<double> >* table;
```

Constructor:

```
     table = new vector<vector<double> >;
```

But now we the way we accessed it before (with [][]) doesn't work.

We tried a dummy class with this:

```
class myClass {
    public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    vector<vector<double> > t;
 };

myClass::myClass() 
{
    t = vector<vector<double> > (10, vector<double>(10));
}
```

But it wouldn't free properly and we got core dumps. Also when we tried to grow the array, we'd have expclitly construct each new row.

Ex:

```
t[50] = vector<double>(5);
t[50][10] = 10;
```

If we didn't do it like this, we'd get a segfault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to resize the tables before you access elements.

```
vector<vector<double> > table;
table.resize(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  table[i].resize(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your vectors are large enough to store your elements. If a vector `t` has size `N`, the last element you can access is `t[N-1]`.

```
t = vector<vector<double> > (10, vector<double>(10));
t[50] = vector<double>(5); // This is wrong! Vector size is 10, you access 50th.
t[50][10] = 10; // Wrong again! Vector size 5, you access 10th.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Boost installed try using [Boost Multi-array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the element in [][] manner by derefrencing.

```
Vector<vector<double>> *table ;
table = new vector<vector<double>> ( n, vector<double>( m, 0.0)) ;
cout << (*table)[i][j] ;
```

Most of the times, this works perfectly well.