# Create a 2D array with variable sized dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to be able to create a 2d array the size of the width and height I read from a file, but I get errors when I say:

```
int array[0][0]
array = new int[width][height]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279643/declaring-dynamic-2d-vector-in-class

Comment: [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Comment: Use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 22):

You should use pointer to pointers :

```
int** array;
array = new int*[width];
for (int i = 0;i<width;i++)
    array[i] = new int[height];
```

and when you finish using it or you want to resize, you should free the allocated memory like this :

```
for (int i = 0;i<width;i++)
    delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;
```

To understand and be able to read more complex types, this link may be useful :

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Hope that's Helpful.

Comment: ...and remember to delete with `delete[]`.

Comment: TAMER I think you need to swap your heights and widths around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
  int **array; // array is a pointer-to-pointer-to-int

    array = malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    if(array == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
        }
    for(i = 0; i < height ; i++)
        {
        array[i] = malloc(width * sizeof(int));
        if(array[i] == NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            exit or return
            }
        }

    array = new int*[width];
    if(array == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
         }
    else
    {
    for (int i = 0;i<width;i++)
        array[i] = new int[height];
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid `malloc` in C++.

Comment: This is a really `C`-ish way to do things. Plus, the `fprintf` calls really have no place here. It could use some cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is rectangular, as in your example, you can do it with just one allocation:

```
int* array = new int[width * height];
```

This effectively flattens the array into a single dimension, and it's much faster.

Of course, this being C++, why don't you use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`?