# How to get length of two dimensional array

Tags: c++

Create a two dimensional dynamic integer array S. The size should be `seq1_length+1` and `seq2_length+1`. If `seq1_length = 10` and seq2_length = 10`answer should be`S[11][11]`.
I used this code

```
S= new int *[len1];
for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
S[i]=new int[len2];
```

How can I check the size of this array supposed to be `S[11][11]`.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508341/create-a-2d-array-with-variable-sized-dimensions

Comment: I am directed to use dynamic array

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do with it. You should say some words about the usage of the array. For an example, there are many matrix libraries out there for number crunching.

Comment: `vector` is how you make a dynamic array in C++

Answer (score 0):

First, you will get compile error "S does not name a type". Correct declaration should be

```
int* S = new int*[len1+1];
for (int i = 0; i < len1+1; i++)
{
    S[i] = new int[len2+1];
}
```

Len1+1 and Len2+1, because you need to have size one greater than `seq1_length` and `seq2_length`. For checking size you can simply do this

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = o; i < len1+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = o; j < len2+1; j++)
    {
        count++;
    }
}

std::cout << count << endl;
```